# How can i make a java program that dynamicaly picks up data from an excel file?

Tags: java, dynamic, algorithmic-trading

I am working on an algorithmic trading strategy and have an excel sheet that dynamically picks up the stock values from the internet. I require my JAVA program to pick up these changing values,store them and perform some operations on them dynamically to generate result. Kindly suggest a method to pick those values or in case anybody has that piece of code, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you heard of Apache POI API to process excel sheets. May be we could suggest something if you could elaborate the problem a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own dsn (Data Source Name).

Go through this link -

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/jdbc-database-tutorials/356-how-connect-excel-spreadsheet-using-jdbc-java.html